# Scatterplot in python

Tags: cluster-analysis, python

I am trying to make a scatter plot with 2-3 variables represented in different colors. I have plotted it but I need a circle to make a boundary around each of the scatter clusters just for the representation. something like below.... how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use K-Means clustering which is one of the easiest ways to create these kinds of clusters. You could use `scikit-learn` to make this easy. I have also done PCA for you and if you don't want to do PCA you could remove that, but I urge you to apply PCA.

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def KMeansModel(n):
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    reduced_train_data = pca.fit_transform(train_data)
    KM = KMeans(n_clusters=n)
    KM.fit(reduced_train_data)
    plt.plot(reduced_train_data[:, 0], reduced_train_data[:, 1], 'k.', markersize=2)
    centroids = KM.cluster_centers_

    for ind,i in enumerate(centroids):
        class_inds=np.where(KM.labels_==ind)[0]
        max_dist=np.max(metrics.pairwise_distances(i, reduced_train_data[class_inds]))
        print(max_dist)
        plt.gca().add_artist(plt.Circle(i, max_dist, fill=False))
    plt.show()

out = ...
```

The `n` here is number of clusters you want to make.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there will be two steps: clustering and constructing a shape around the clusters.

You appear to have got the clustering sorted. I recommend for the shape you bound the clusters by ellipsoids. There are a few ways of constructing such ellipsoids.

A simple one is to construct Legendre ellipsoids, that is ellipsoids centered at the mean, 
$$
c_i = \frac1n \sum \vec x_i
$$
and defined by
$$
(x_i - c_i) a^{-1} (x_j - c_j) \le 1
$$
where
$$
a_{ij} = \frac1n (x _i - c_i) (x_j - c_j)  ( d + 2)
$$

You may need to expand the ellipsoids as Legendre ellipsoids are not gaurenteed to bound all the points.